# Why is my program not compiling?

Tags: c, cs50

My code is suppose to initialise any word you type but it is refusing to compile
.
I don't understand the error messages it is giving to me.

> 1  initialize.c:24:23: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the
>         address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
>
> 2 initialize.c:21:23: error: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Werror,-Wformat-security]
>
> 3 initialize.c:21:23: error: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Werror,-Wformat-security]
>                  printf(toupper(s[i]));

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void initialize(string s);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{ 
     printf("May I have your name?");
     string name = GetString();
     initialize(name);

}
void initialize(string s)
{    
     int space = 1;

     for (int i = 0;i < strlen(s); i++)
     {     if(space == 1)
           {
               printf(toupper(s[i])); 
               space -= 1;
           }       
           if(strncmp(s[i]," ",1 ) )  
           {

                space += 1;         

           }
     }


}
```

Comment: my complier is clang

Comment: Another issue is `strncmp(s[i]," ",1 )`  . `s[i]` isn't a string. I guess you meant `s[i] == ' '`.

Comment: strongly suggest not using the header file cs50.h as it is not portable.   To allow not including cs50.h, change the 'string' types (3 places) to 'char *'

Comment: when compiling, always enable all warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  then fix the warnings.   A good start would be: the main parameters are not used, so change the main() function declaration to: 'int main( void )'

Comment: strlen(), sizeof(), etc return a 'size_t' which is defined as a 'unsigned long int' not a 'int'  so when making comparisons, best that all parties to the comparison are 'unsigned long int'

Comment: while the latest versions of C allow the return statement in the main() function to be missing, the OS is expecting a returned value and will look at the register that is expected to contain the return value.  So best to be in the habit of always including the return statement.

Comment: the printf() function requires a format string, followed by parameters, if any

Comment: use the function fgets() to replace the function: GetString()

Comment: the posted code, after the compiler warnings are fixed, outputs the very first letter of the input (capitalized) then outputs the first letter after a space letter (capitalized)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects a format string with type `const char*` as its 1st argument, so:

change

```
printf(toupper(s[i]));
```

to

```
printf("%c", toupper(s[i]));
```

And as @Matt McNabb pointed, [strncmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) has the similar problem here. Because you tend to compare the 1st char only, you chould change

```
if(strncmp(s[i]," ",1 ) )
```

to

```
if (s[i] == ' ')
```

to make it clearer and more effective.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code, after making it portable

But not handling user input errors

It has the necessary corrections so it cleanly compiles

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void initialize(char * s);

int main( void )
{
     printf("May I have your name?");
     char name[50] = {'\0'};
     fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin ); // should check returned value
                                        // to assure the line input was successful

     initialize(name);
     return 0;
} // end function: main


void initialize(char * s)
{
    int space = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0;i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if(space == 1)
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(s[i]));
            space -= 1;
        }

        if( ' ' == s[i] ) // always place literal on left so compiler
                          // catches any place where '=' was used
                          // when it should have been '=='
        {
            space += 1;
        }
    }
} // end function: initialize
```